# No se muestran los resultados de mi datatable en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Buenas verán tengo un datatable el cual debería llenarse al realizar una búsqueda por meses y año, el problema es que me muestra que me trae los datos por  la consola,pero el datatable no se llena trabajo con codeigniter.

este es mi js donde creo el datatable

```
$(document).on("click", "#buscar", function () {
 var meses = $("#meses").val();
 var year = $("#year").val();

      $('#lisForm').dataTable({    
      "processing": true,
       "serverSide": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
       "bJQueryUI": true,
    "ajax": {
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': 'reportes_formato/bus_mes_year',
        'data': {
       meses: meses,
       year: year,

    },
    'columnDefs': [
         Personalizar algunas celdas
        {// Celda de ID no visible
             "targets": [10],
             "visible": false,
             "searchable": false
         },
         {// Celda de ID no visible
             "targets": [11],
             "visible": false,
             "searchable": false
         },
         {// Crear celda adicional para botones de ver, editar y eliminar
             "targets": [1],
             "data": null,
             "width": '135px',
             "defaultContent": '<div align="center"></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" title="Editar datos" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs fa fa-list-alt dt_cit_ver"></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" title="Nueva Evolución Médica" class="btn btn-success btn-xs fa fa-file-o dt_hoj_evo"></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" title="Historial de Evolución" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs fa fa-file-text-o dt_evo_ver"></a></div>'
         },

    ]

}
 });
     });
```

y en mi controlador es donde le envio los datos para llenar el datatable el cual llamo una función que cree en postgres el cual funciona perfectamente cuando le paso los parametros de mes y año

```
 public function bus_mes_year(){
     $meses = $_POST['meses'];
     $year = $_POST['year'];


      $table = "fn_bus_mes_year($meses, $year)";
      $primaryKey = 'id_for';

    $columns = array(
        array('db' => 'id_for', 'dt' => 0),
        array('db' => 'item', 'dt' => 2),
        array('db' => 'tipo', 'dt' => 3),
        array('db' => 'titulo', 'dt' => 4),
        array('db' => 'codigo', 'dt' => 5),
        array('db' => 'uni_adm','dt' => 6),           
        array('db' => 'fec_rec_int', 'dt' => 7),
        array('db' => 'num_for_apr','dt' => 8),
        array('db' => 'tiempo_asig_act', 'dt' => 9),
        array('db' => 'meses', 'dt' => 10),
        array('db' => 'years', 'dt' => 11),           
    );

    //Condiciones adicionales para el WHERE
    $filtroAdd = " id_for  <> 0 "; // 

    //Parámetros de conexión
    $pg_details = array('user' => USUDB, 'pass' => CLADB, 'db' => NOMDB, 'host' => SERDB);
    echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple($_POST, $pg_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $filtroAdd));

    //print trim($cedula);die;

   $result =$this->reportes_model->bus_mes_year($meses, $year);
       // print_r($result);die;
        if ($result == NULL){
            $mensaje="No hay registros guardados intente con otra fecha";
            print_r(json_encode($mensaje));
        }else{
        print json_encode($result);
        }

}
```

y esta es mi vista

```
<div class="box-body">
          <tbody>

                    <h4 style="margin-left: 20px;"> Buscador:</h4>
                    <tr id="filter_col2" data-column="2" >
                        <td align="center" style="width: 134px"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="meses" placeholder="Mes"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="filter_col10" data-column="10">
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="year" placeholder="Año"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><button id="buscar">Buscar</button></tr>
                    <tr><button class="icon-microsoftexcel" id="consulta"><a href="<?php print $base_url ?>formatos/excel"></a></button></tr>
                </tbody>
            <table id="lisForm" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id_for</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Tipo</th>
                        <th>Titulo del manual</th>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Unidad administrativa que ejecuta</th>
                        <th>Fecha de recepción (interna)</th>
                        <th>Número de formato de aprobación</th>
                        <th>Tiempo asignado para la asignación de la actividad</th>
                        <th>Meses</th>
                        <th>Año</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>


        </div>
```

al realizar la búsqueda me muestra lo siguiente en consola 
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[{"0":"2","2":"2","3":"AR","4":"PROPUESTA DE CREACION DE AREAS DE TRABAJO","5":"F-OPF-028-15","6":"OPF","7":"2015-02-18","8":"EN EJECUCION","9":"1 SEMANA","10":"2","11":"2015"},{"0":"3","2":"3","3":"AR","4":"PROPUESTA DE CREACION DE AREAS DE TRABAJO","5":"F-OPF-028-15","6":"OPP","7":"2015-02-18","8":"EN EJECUCION","9":"1 SEMANA","10":"2","11":"2015"},{"0":"5","2":"5","3":"AR","4":"PROPUESTA DE CREACION DE AREAS DE TRABAJO","5":"F-OPF-028-15","6":"OPP","7":"2015-02-18","8":"EN EJECUCION","9":"1 SEMANA","10":"2","11":"2015"}]}[{"id_for":"2","item":"2","tipo":"AR","titulo":"PROPUESTA DE CREACION DE AREAS DE TRABAJO","codigo":"F-OPF-028-15","uni_adm":"OPF","fec_rec_int":"2015-02-18","num_for_apr":"EN EJECUCION","tiempo_asig_act":"1 SEMANA","meses":"2","years":"2015"},{"id_for":"3","item":"3","tipo":"AR","titulo":"PROPUESTA DE CREACION DE AREAS DE TRABAJO","codigo":"F-OPF-028-15","uni_adm":"OPF","fec_rec_int":"2015-02-18","num_for_apr":"EN EJECUCION","tiempo_asig_act":"1 SEMANA","meses":"2","years":"2015"},{"id_for":"5","item":"5","tipo":"AR","titulo":"CREACION DE AREAS DE TRABAJO","codigo":"F-OPF-028-15","uni_adm":"OPF","fec_rec_int":"2015-02-18","num_for_apr":"EN EJECUCION","tiempo_asig_act":"1 SEMANA","meses":"2","years":"2015"}]

y el datatable me da este error
DataTables warning: table id=lisForm - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

No se que error pueda ser puesto que no me muestra ningún error.

Comment: El error indica que la llamada no te está devolveno un json bien formado, por lo que veo en tu output de consola parece que primero tienes un json object y despues un array de json. Prueba a hacer un `json_decode(response)` a la respuesta de la llamada ajax

Comment: En la respuesta hay dos elementos: 1º un objeto JSON, 2º un array de objetos JSON. Por lo tanto, estás devolviendo dos cosas, por eso no lo reconoce. ¿Necesitas esos dos elementos? entonces debes combinarlos válidamente, ¿necesitas solamente uno de ellos?, entonces devuelve sólo el que necesites.

Comment: utilice json_decode en mi respuesta de este modo print json_decode($result); y me sale el siguiente error print json_decode($result); y si comento esa linea me genera la tabla pero antes me suelta este error table id=lisForm - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0):

Envia un header con el tipo de Content-Type a *application/json*.
Y tambien cambia el print por un echo.

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($result);
```